# How to add round brackets to strings in column

Tags: python, addition, brackets

I have a data frame with strings in Column_A: row1:Anna, row2:Mark, row3:Emy

I would like to get something like:row1(Anna). row2:(Mark), row3:(Emy)

I have found some examples on how to remove the brackets, however have not found anything on how to add them.

Hence, any clue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using apply form pandas you can create a function which adds the brackets. In this case the function is an lambda function using the f-string.

```
df['Column_A'] = df['Column_A'].apply(lambda x: f'({x})')

# Example:
l = ['Anna', 'Mark', 'Emy']
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Column_A'])

  Column_A
0     Anna
1     Mark
2      Emy

df['Column_A'] = df['Column_A'].apply(lambda x: f'({x})')

  Column_A
0   (Anna)
1   (Mark)
2    (Emy)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Approach 1:** Using direct Concatenation (Simpler)

```
df['Column_A'] = '(' + df['Column_A'] + ')'
```

[image: Output 1]

> **Approach 2:** Using apply() function and f-strings

```
df.Column_A.apply(lambda val: f'({val})')
```

[image: Output 2]

> **Approach 3:** Using map() function

```
df = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda val: f'({val})', df.Column_A))
```

[image: Output 3]